# How do I set relative dates in Directus?

Tags: content-management-system, directus

In settings>interfaces>dates, I want to turn off the "relative" toggle, but when I flip that toggle it seems to turn itself back on as soon as I leave the screen, so the setting isn't taking.

This setting works in other interface options like "datetime", but appears not to work in "dates". Does anyone have any tips to solve this? Thank you!

Edit: there are some related open issues like [this one](https://github.com/directus/app/issues/2526), but I was unable to find anything directly relevant. I also don't see any obvious option to save.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently looking just at templates for all interfaces. `settings/interfaces` doesn't have to do anything with settings but is there to help development of interfaces.

Heres how you can change that setting:

1. Goto `settings/collection & fields`
2. Select a collection where a Date-Time field is present.
3. Select the Date-Time field.
   You will now the this popup:
   [image]

4. Here you can change the the time preview to relative. There is no global switch for your information.